# Why am I getting a 'Chrome failed to start' error when trying to run Selenium and FastAPI in Docker on DigitalOcean container?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, fastapi

In my Fast API Project some function need to be use selenium for scrap data when i run it in local. It's work but when i make a dockerfile and run it in digitalocean container it not work. I can see /docs but when i call some api and this api function use selenium i have error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/web/scb_getstatement_api/main.py", line 162, in get_statement
    resault = get_statementscb(session, username, password,login)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/web/scb_getstatement_api/main.py", line 106, in get_statementscb
    session = getscb_session(username, password)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/web/scb_getstatement_api/main.py", line 23, in getscb_session
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Some one can help me please?
this it my docker file

```
FROM python:3
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /web/scb_getstatement_api

# Copy project files
COPY main.py ./
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 ca-certificates
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

RUN pip3 install selenium chromedriver-autoinstaller

RUN groupadd -r chrome && useradd -r -g chrome -G audio,video chrome \
    && mkdir -p /home/chrome && chown -R chrome:chrome /home/chrome
USER chrome

# Expose port for FastAPI
EXPOSE 5000

# Run the FastAPI server
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5006"]
```

can run selenium and googlechrome headless with fastapi on digitalocean container

Comment: Are you actually trying to run Chrome with a GUI in a headless environment, and then asking why it's not working?

Comment: my webdriver have oppion --headless but it still not work I don't know why pls help
        
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)